# Kubernetes : configuring custom influxdb sink for heapster running in kube-system namespace

Tags: kubernetes, influxdb, heapster

I need to configure Heapster to collect the metrics for my custom kubernetes and store it in the my own influx . 
I made the changes in Heapster.yaml for source & sink configuration but this doesnt work . Below are the values change

- --source=kubernetes:https://
- --sink=influxdb:http://:8086 .

It creates k8s database in influx but the measurements are not getting generated

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: you have to explain your problem in more details. explain what changes you have made and what error you are getting.

Comment: I made the changes in source & sink values in heapster.yaml as below                                                                                    
        - --source=kubernetes:https://<servername>
        - --sink=influxdb:http://<influx ip>:8086 .   It creates k8s database in inlfux but the measurments are not getting generated

Comment: you should provide these information in question. not in comment.

Comment: Have you exposed the influxdb? Did you checked if those pods can see each other?